# Failed test #2. Wrong answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

The input for this program are two sets. Each set in a separate line; elements of the set are space separated.

Your program must output the symmetric difference of these sets.

**Example**

Symmetric difference of the sets {1, 2, 3} and {0, 1, 2} equals to {0, 3}.

**Sample Input:**

```
1 2 3
0 1 2
```

**Sample Output:**

```
0 3
```

**My Solution :**

```
set_1 = set(input())
set_2 = set(input())

difference_set1 = set_1 - set_2
difference_set2 = set_2 - set_1

for x in difference_set1:
    difference_set2.add(x)

for x in difference_set2:
    print(x, end=' ')
```

Test Results are failing... Can somebody please explain :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code works fine. Below is the driver test for the same.

```
IN : 1 2 3
IN : 0 1 2

OUT : 0 3
```

But, there is a small `logical mistake`.You are not handling your inputs properly. But in the end, fortunately for you, it *cancels out the problem* it might create.

They should be :

```
set_1 = set(map(int,input().split()))
set_2 = set(map(int,input().split()))

#OR just

set_1 = set(input().split())
set_2 = set(input().split())
```

A quick glance at the workings of your code and the correct code.

```
>>> s = set(input())                          #your code
    1 2 3
>>> s
=> {'1', '2', ' ', '3'}

>>> s = set(map(int, input().split()))        #should be
    1 2 3
>>> s
=> {1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: Not that it's conceptually better, or better at all, but you don't need to map the split to int; you can just work with the split strings instead.

Comment: @EnricoBorba , I know. But since the sample output seems to be `int` , just kept it so.

Comment: It worked...thanks for the quick reply.
Is there any way to lower it's complexity ? 
Right now, it showed 12.65 complexity score and best complexity score is 4.12.

Comment: @AjaiVeerSingh: Python sets have [symmetric difference](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference) operator `^`, you could try to use that.

Comment: @Niemmi, thanks... It worked great... my complexity score is 8.54

Answer (score 1):

Let's print your inputs:

```
input_set = set(input())
print(input_set)
```

- For the input `1 2 3`, it prints `{' ', '3', '1', '2'}`
- For the input `1,2,3`, it prints `{',', '3', '1', '2'}`
- For the input `123`, it prints `{'3', '1', '2'}`

As you can see, your inputs are problematic.

You can use inputs without spaces such as `123` and `012`.

Or, if you want to use space between 2 numbers, you can use `split()`:

```
input_set = set(input().split())
print(input_set)
```

Input:

```
1 2 3
```

Output:

```
{'3', '2', '1'}
```